# In frame by frame animation java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: android, animation, memory-leaks

I try to load animation on button click . I have **90 images** in resources folder, and i try to load them , each image has approx. size **50kb** when i click button start  animation i got exception as OutOfmemory .Please check following code .  Any help will be appreciated.

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    startbtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.myStartButton);
    stopbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.myStopButton);
    startbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    stopbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    images=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);

    images.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.demo_animation);

    AniFrame = (AnimationDrawable)images.getBackground();



}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.myStartButton)
    {
        AniFrame.start();
    }else if(v.getId()==R.id.myStopButton)
    {
        AniFrame.stop();
    }

}
```

Comment: Look at the "Related" questions on the right side of the page.  You will see this question has been covered ad nauseum.

Comment: I see the related questions but not get the proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

Are the images compressed (jpg or png)? I think when they are loaded into memory they are converted to bitmap format, and use much more memory (up to 4 bytes per pixel).
That is probably the cause of your outofmemoryexception. You can't calculate 90x50kb as on disk, think in 90 x 750Kb.